# SONAR: Replace this lambda with a method reference

Tags: lambda, java-8, sonarqube

I am getting following warning on Sonar:

Replace this lambda with a method reference

Code is :

```
protected List<Test> getTests(List<String> testIds) {
    List<Test> tests = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(testIds)) {
        testIds.stream().forEach(eachTestId -> tests.add(getTest(eachTestId)));
    }
    return tests;
}
```

How can I get over this warning?

Comment: I can’t say anything about this obviously wrong warning, but the whole Stream usage is against the purpose of that API. If you just want to perform an action via `forEach`, you can simply call `forEach` on the collection. In either case, you don’t need to check for an empty collection. If you are only using `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` for the `null` test, you should perform a clean `null` check instead. But actually, you want to do `return testIds.stream().map(id -> getTest(id)) .collect(Collectors.toList());` instead of using `forEach`. *Then* you can indeed use a method reference for `getTest`

Comment: As developer of the java analyzer for SonarQube : Warning is indeed wrong but could you precise which version of the java analyzer you are using ? as this was most likely fixed in the latest releases ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mark your `getTest` as `static` and write your method with using references as follows:

```
protected List<Test> getTests(List<String> testIds) {

    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(testIds)) {
          return new ArrayList<Test>();
    }

    return testIds.stream()
          .map(Test::getTest)
          .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Test>::new));
}
```

Comment: Note that you don’t need an explicit type as in `ArrayList<Test>::new`, you can simply use `ArrayList::new`. Besides that, `CollectionUtils.isEmpty(testIds)` is obsolete, the Stream API will handle empty lists, thus, the `CollectionUtils.isEmpty` test is merely an obfuscated `null` test. So *if* that is intended, `if(testIds==null) return new ArrayList<>();` makes that clear. Alternatively, you can use `return (testIds==null? Stream.<String>empty(): testIds.stream()) .map(…) .collect(…);`, which makes it easier to change the returned `List` type if desired, e.g. using `Collectors.toList()`…